# onTimeChangedListener is not firing

Tags: android

I'm working through the Big Nerd Ranch Android programming book. I'm working on the CriminalIntent project and am trying to setup a DatePicker and TimePicker to set the date and time of the "crime." My DatePicker dialog works fine, when the date is changed, everything updates properly, no issues there.

The problem comes in the TimePicker. For some reason, the onTimeChangedListener doesn't seem to be firing, and thus, the time doesn't update properly. I've copied in my code for setting the listener to the TimePicker. I have a log statement that never fires when I change the time, which is why I think this is where the issue is.

```
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_picker);
    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // Get the date
            date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute).getTime();
            Log.d("TimePickerFragment", "hour: " + hourOfDay + "; minute: " + minute);

            // Save this date
            getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_TIME, date);
        }
    });
```

And here is the code where I set the hour and minute:

```
date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_TIME);

    // Create a calendar to get hour, minute, and AM/PM info
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int amPm = cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM); // 0 = AM 1 = PM
    year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

If you need any other code let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TimePickerDialog` and `OnTimeSetListener`;put your code inside listener's method `onTimeSet`. This will be called when user choose a time.

```
Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
int mHour = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mMinute = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute).getTime();
        Log.d("TimePickerFragment", "hour: " + hourOfDay + "; minute: " + minute);
        getArguments().putSerializable(EXTRA_TIME, date);
    }
}, mHour, mMinute, true);
mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
mTimePicker.show();
```

Comment: For this, I am extending my fragment from DialogFragment, would I instead only extend it from Fragment? It looks like using TimePickerDialog will pop up the dialog I need?

Comment: Yeah it would pop up a dialog. You just use this code in your fragment. It will automatically open the dialog. Just change `this` to `getActivity()`.

Comment: Hmm, that pops up a dialog, but it's a bit buggy. Is there anyway to use the original method to get it to recognize that the time has changed? I'm using the onCreateDialog instead of onCreate, and am returning the dialog I create, this also allows me to send data back to my original fragment with the changed time in a way that is easy to do.

Comment: EDIT: I did some code movement and no longer needed my dialog fragment, I called it directly from the fragment I needed the data in, worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Prior to Lollipop(5.0), TimePicker view would fire an onTimeChanged event each time when the time changed, allowing an app to
dynamically react to the time currently specified by the picker.

In Lollipop, the Timepicker came with

android:timePickerMode="clock"

In Clock mode, the onTimeChanged events is not getting fired, when the time is changed.

So the Optimal way is better go with    **android:timePickerMode="spinner"**

```
<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timepick_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
```