# API 21 How Do I Get The Selected Time?

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to build an alarm app of sorts and am pretty amateurish at coding. This is my current code.

```
public void Execute(View view){
    testView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teslaView);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    long month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    long day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    long hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    long minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    long seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    String totalString = (String) String.valueOf(currentSeconds(seconds, minute, hour, day, month));
```

I have a TimePicker that I want to use for people to select their desired times with and I have looked at the Android Documentation but am confused as to what to do with the results of my findings.

I know I want to use this command ([LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getHour()))

But am confused on what to do.

Do I get an instance first like I did with the calender or do I do something along the lines of `TimePicker myPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
Integer myHour = getHour();`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can make use of AlarmManager. For reference check this https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a bit wrong ..

```
myPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

int hour = myPick.getCurrentHour();
int minute = myPick.getCurrentMinute();
```

That's all you need to get current hour and minutes

Answer (score 1):

Pertain to this :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html

check this : [onTimeChangedListener is not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749031/ontimechangedlistener-is-not-firing)